# Preimage of surjective linear function from subgroup to base field has same number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GF(p^n)$ where $p$ is a prime.

Let $Z_p$ denote the base field $GF(p)$.
Consider the linear function $f: G \rightarrow Z_p$.
Let $|f^{-1}(c)|$ denote the number of elements $x \in G$ such that $f(x) = c$.
If $f$ is surjective, then for $c, c' \in Z_p$, $$|f^{-1}(c)| = |f^{-1}(c')|.$$

I have seen this statement used many times in proofs but I'm a little unclear about why this is true. Can anyone give a proof or intuition, please?

I think this post solves my problem.

[Prove the two preimage sets have the same size under a surjective group homomorphism (for a finite group)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052175/prove-the-two-preimage-sets-have-the-same-size-under-a-surjective-group-homomorp)

Comment: This is true for any group homomorphism or linear transformation: The number of preimages of a point in the image is equal to the cardinality of the kernel.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the pointer. I found it at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052175/prove-the-two-preimage-sets-have-the-same-size-under-a-surjective-group-homomorp

Comment: It's true for any group homomorphism, whether the group is finite or not. If the preimage is not empty, then any two have the same cardinality.